# MediaPlayer is not playing sound

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a Media Player. But when I press button (play) it shows error.

```
08-20 11:35:21.473: D/MediaPlayer(775): Couldn't open file on client side, trying    server side

08-20 11:35:21.493: E/MediaPlayer(775): error (1, -2147483648)

08-20 11:35:21.503: W/System.err(775): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

my code is

```
btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Uri audio = Uri.parse("android.resourse://vishesh.MediaPlayer/res/drawable/jannat");
            try {

                mp.setDataSource(Play.this,audio);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            btnplay.setText("Pause");

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the audio format? it it supported format?

Comment: please store your audio file in raw folder. and try 3gp or wav format

Comment: audio format of my file is mp3

Comment: Did you mean `android.resource`(with a **c**)?

Comment: @Vishesh : Why are you trying to play a file in the `drawable` directory?

Comment: @Michael yes   i am using android.resource

Comment: @Squonk is there any problem to play a file in the drawable directory?

Comment: @Vishesh : I've no idea but it's bad coding practice to put an audio file into `drawable` which is meant to contain only images. Also, you don't provide a file extension - if I play I file with `MediaPlayer` I specify `filename.ext` such as `jannat.mp3`. The `MediaPlayer` class expects an absolute path.

Comment: @Squonk thanks . but i used in raw folder also but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to place or put such .mp3 or any other files would be in the assets folder.

These files once stored will become a part of your android app itself and can be read easily.

Play sound from Asset.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
 player = new MediaPlayer();
 player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
 player.prepare();
 player.start();
```

Comment: Can you place your sound file in asset folder?.

Comment: thanks sir its working correctly if i put my mp3 file in asset folder
but now it playing sound first time only. 
second time it is not playing sound

Comment: there are two buttons one for play and second for stop.
first time i click on play button it works correctly and click on stop button also work correct.
but if i click on play button again then it shows error